# Joining two time series based on id and time

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to join two time series based on a ID variable.

My first time series,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

id <- c(11, 11, 11, 12, 12)
time <- c("2020-11", "2020-12", "2021-01", "2020-12", "2021-01")
values <- c(10, 20, 25, 100, 200)
data1 <- data.frame(id, time, values)
data1$time <- ym(data1$time)
```

The second time series is as follows,

```
time <- c("2020-10", "2020-11", "2020-12", "2021-01", "2020-12", "2021-01", "2021-02")
trend <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
data2 <- data.frame(Time, trend)
data2$time <- ym(data2$time)
```

Notice that, the first data frame has 5 rows and the second one has 7. The joined data frame should have 5 rows.

Now I want to join the second data frame into the first by id and date. I am doing the following,

```
newdata <- dplyr::inner_join(data1, data2, by = "time")
newdata
> newData
  id       Time values trend
1 11 2020-11-01     10   0.2
2 11 2020-12-01     20   0.3
3 11 2020-12-01     20   0.5
4 11 2021-01-01     25   0.4
5 11 2021-01-01     25   0.6
6 12 2020-12-01    100   0.3
7 12 2020-12-01    100   0.5
8 12 2021-01-01    200   0.4
9 12 2021-01-01    200   0.6
```

This is not what I want. There are repeatation in the id. The data frame has 9 rows instead of 5. My expected output should look like,

```
> newData
  id       time values trend
1 11 2020-11-01     10   0.2
2 11 2020-12-01     20   0.3
3 11 2021-01-01     25   0.4
4 12 2020-12-01    100   0.3
5 12 2021-01-01    200   0.4
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `match` to get the position and extract the corresponding value

```
newData <- data1
newData$trend <- data2$trend[match(data1$time, data2$time)]
```

-output

```
 newData
  id       time values trend
1 11 2020-11-01     10   0.2
2 11 2020-12-01     20   0.3
3 11 2021-01-01     25   0.4
4 12 2020-12-01    100   0.3
5 12 2021-01-01    200   0.4
```

---

If we do `merge` or join with duplicate `by` in both datasets, it will result in a cartesian join